# Links don't work after success ajax form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am using jQuery 1.7.1 and I am submitting an ajax form. On success, I am returning some text with a link. When I click on the link, it doesn't work. I also want to submit the form via a link rather than a submit button. Here is what I have so far, the submit works ok.

```
$(function () {
    var myformselector = "#UploadFile";
    $(myformselector).submit(function (e) {
        //prevent Default functionality
        e.preventDefault();
        var values = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: '[file]',
            type: 'post',
            data: values,
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#loader').show();
                $('#UploadFile').fadeOut('slow');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#UploadFile").html(data);
                $("#UploadFile").fadeIn('slow');
                $("#loader").hide();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Is your id `#UploadFile` or `UploadFile` ?

Comment: Because # is the ID selector, so #UploadFile would select the id UploadFile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have `#` in your element's ID.

may be you meant `var myformselector = "#UploadFile"` & then `$(myformselector)` would make sense.

You used it for all the selectors & you need to update each one of them

Comment: sorry, i was  meant to remove one of the #... in coldfusion you need to escape hashes using ##

Comment: @Marios - ok, how are you handling the click event? can you post that code in your question as well.

Comment: <form id="UploadFile" name="UploadFile" action="" method="Post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="submit" value="submit" name="btnUpload"/></form>    Ideally i would like to use a link ... but the main issue is that the links in the success html dont work...the links are correct but you cant click them